# Need Assistance: XCP-NG Fails to Boot Up After Disk Error

Tags: linux, centos, hpe, xcp-ng

I am seeking assistance with an issue I am facing in my XCP-NG configuration on an HPE DL360 G7 server. Despite using this server for about a year without any problems, I recently encountered an issue after cleaning it with a compressor.

Here's the situation: I unintentionally mispositioned a disk during the cleaning process. Upon restarting the server, a message indicating a faulty disk appeared. I promptly powered off the server, corrected the disk placement, and restarted the server. However, my XCP-NG instance no longer starts. Instead, I receive the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw2v8.jpg)

(see image for complete message)

> ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected SPCR Access Width. Defaulting to byte size.
>
> Initramfs unpacking failed: junk in compressed archive.
>
> APEI: Can not request [mem....] for APEI ERST registers
>
> Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unkown-block(0,0)

It's worth noting that before shutting down the server for cleaning, I performed a complete system update. There's a possibility that this update may have caused damage to the system.

As a self-taught individual, I am aware that there might be gaps in my knowledge, and I am reaching out to the community for advice on diagnosing and resolving this issue.

I have already attempted to find solutions to this problem, but most of the information available pertains to issues on Ubuntu, not XCP-NG. Moreover, the solutions provided seem to be specific to Ubuntu and do not apply to my situation.

Here are the available boot options in GRUB :
[grub boot options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kspNl.png)

Comment: `using this server for about a year without any problems` the G7 model is 15 years old. Hardware fails eventually.

Comment: I am facing a software problem, not hardware.

Comment: It is a problem with the "hardware" if the "vendor" of your "software" does not support your "hardware".

Comment: XCP-NG supports the DL360 G7 hardware, it has been working with me for more than a year now, I don't understand what you are trying to say. XCP-NG is built upon CentOS Linux, which is extensively employed in conjunction with servers of this nature

Comment: "after cleaning it with a compressor", please don't do this, it's dangerous.

Comment: "ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected SPCR Access Width. Defaulting to byte size." is with high chance the reason for your problem. You should revert to your former OS version or use a kernel with complete support for SPCR.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe more specifically what you did with "cleaning it with a compressor"
(sorry that should have been a comment, but I cannot post it as such)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/573998)